# Dashing reading out of 2 different CSV's

Tags: ruby

Hello everyone I'm currently trying to get my Dashboard working properly, however I cannot figure out a way to get the values into something my List Widget can read.

```
  begin
    id = 1
    names.each do |item| 
      label = names[id][0] #names = names.csv path
      value = host_status[id]['status'] #host_status = host_status.csv path
      items = { label: label, value: value }
      id += 1
    end
  rescue      
  end

  send_event('hosts', { items: items })
```

So what this script should do is :

- write the host_status.csv with the values it gets from the status.cgi (working)
- iterate through both the host_status.csv and names.csv getting values from both of them
- output should be something like this (label comes from names.csv, value from host_status.csv) =>

  {label: "localhost", value: "UP"}, {label: "USV", value: "UP"}

The list widget needs something like an Array in a Hash with the keys label and value as far as I can tell, however my script doesnt return anything is there something like a push method for hashes?

Comment: Shorten your code to isolate the specific thing you're asking, few people will look through this whole code since it contains a lot of irrelevant things to the question.

Comment: are your ids really sequential? they go on forever? can you add the piece about where you get your id values from? (or at the very least show us what the data looks like in the `names` and `host_status` objects.

Comment: Because i put it in names.each it should only iterate until it reaches the end since I dont want it to put the headers into the dataoutput i start at id 1 and use a begin rescue end block to break out once it reaches the end  names.csv looks like this (displayname | name | host/service)   host_status like this ( host_name | host_display_name | status |...) thats one row each

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that names is an array of arrays `[['foo'], ['bar']]`

and that host_status is an array of objects `[{'status' => 'foo'}, {'status' => 'bar'}]`

you should just be able to do

```
names = [['foo'], ['bar']]
host_status = [{'status' => 'foo'}, {'status' => 'bar'}]
labels = names.map(&:first) # ['foo', 'bar']
values = host_status.map {|s| s['status'] } # ['foo', 'bar']

# zip zips together two arrays [['foo', 'foo'], ['bar', 'bar']]
# inject iterates over the array and returns a new data structure
items = labels.zip(values).inject([]) do |memo, (k,v)|
  memo.push({label: k, value:v})
  memo
end
```

You should just be able to run that code sample in an irb session.

Enumerable#map:http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map

Enumerable#zip: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip

Enumerable#inject: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

Comment: Sorry im quite new to ruby let me try to say what that code does and please tell me if im wrong. labels becomes an array of the names.csv + gets inserted a symbol named :first. values becomes an array of the arrays in the host_status.csv specifically the column 'status' in there. items becomes a new array that both holds labels and values k + v are the corresponding data of each labels and values which are pushed into memo. but what does the last memo mean?

Comment: added some comments to the code example. map takes a block. short hand for a block when just calling a method on the items in the list is `&block` so first just calls `first` on each array in the list. it is the idiomatic way to get the first value instead of `[0]`. With inject you have to return the memo object, so that you can add to it in the next iteration through the list. because the array being passed in to inject have two elements, you can destructure the incoming elements into `k` and `v` such that you can assemble the object and push it onto the array `memo`